# Using c#, how do I copy a symbolic link in Windows Vista,7,2008

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, symlink

Using c#, how do I copy a symbolic link in Windows Vista,7,2008.

When I use File.Copy to copy a symlink, its target gets copied.

I wish to mimic the behavior one gets when you use xcopy with the /B option.

Is this possible using .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Win32 `CopyFileEx` function to do this. It took a bit of effort, but here is the whole `CopyFileEx` helper class (C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5 Client Profile compatible and tested!). You can also reuse it for any other `CopyFileEx` tasks that you have:

```
  using System;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public static class CopyHelper
  {
    [Flags]
    public enum CopyFileFlags : uint
    {
        COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS              = 0x00000001,
        COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE                 = 0x00000002,
        COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE       = 0x00000004,
        COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008,
        COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK                = 0x00000800 //NT 6.0+
    }

    public enum CopyProgressResult : uint
    {
        PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
        PROGRESS_CANCEL   = 1,
        PROGRESS_STOP     = 2,
        PROGRESS_QUIET    = 3
    }

    public enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
    {
        CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
        CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH  = 0x00000001
    }

    public delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(
        long TotalFileSize,
        long TotalBytesTransferred,
        long StreamSize,
        long StreamBytesTransferred,
        uint dwStreamNumber,
        CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
        IntPtr hSourceFile,
        IntPtr hDestinationFile,
        IntPtr lpData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]   
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]   
    public static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, 
        string lpNewFileName, CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, 
        IntPtr lpData, ref bool pbCancel, CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);
  }
```

Here is some sample code that shows how to use it to copy a symbolic link (and not the file it refers to):

```
  string srcLink = @"c:\l.txt"; // Sample source soft link
  string destFile = @"d:\l.txt"; // Sample destination soft link
  bool bCancel = false; 
  bool bSuccess = CopyHelper.CopyFileEx(srcLink, destFile,
                    null, IntPtr.Zero, ref bCancel, 
                    CopyHelper.CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK);   
  if (!bSuccess)   
  {   
      int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();   
      throw new Win32Exception(error);   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for links (neither hardlinks, softlinks or symbolic links) in the .NET framework.

You must either call [`mklink.exe`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/) with `Process.Start` and create the link you want,
or you have a look for a third party library which is able to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=CopyFileEx&namespace=%5bAll%5d) and call [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852%28VS.85%29.aspx). Note the `COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK` which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this is a fairly old thread, but I've just finished some work in C code (*yes, really*) that supports this. Posting because I searched all over for this information, and it was not easy to find.

Sadly `CopyFileEx` with `COPY_FILE_SYMLINK` does not do the trick. That simply creates a 0-size file in the target directory with the correct name, but no symbolic link. Another old article contains a solution you could try to implement: [How to copy directory symbolic link as a link to the target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113324/how-to-copy-directory-symbolic-link-as-a-link-to-the-target/68552709#68552709).

I do think the problem with `CopyFileEx` is a bug, one that still exists in Windows 10.