# How to copy directory symbolic link as a link to the target?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems, ntfs

Say, I created a directory symbolic link using the [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) command as such:

mklink /d "test dir link1" "dest dir"

How can I copy it as a link to the target directory? When I try to use the CopyFileEx API and the [COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag as such:

```
::CopyFileEx(L"D:\\Path to source\\test dir link1",
    L"D:\\Path to destination\\test dir link1 copy",
    NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK);
```

it returns error code `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

PS. I tried running my process elevated (just in unlikely scenario that I need to run elevated) and it still gave me the same error code.

Comment: test you have both read and write access as needed and the file has proper ownership/mode. Whether it is a link, file, directory, or otherwise, it is considered a 'file' for linux/gcc computing purposes. So check the basics first.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I'm asking this for Windows OS. And yes, I have the proper ownership of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking to copy a directory using the `CopyFileEx` API. The fact that it's a symbolic link doesn't get resolved until after the check that it's a directory, which means you can't use this API to copy a directory symlink.

Directory symlinks are treated slightly differently from file symlinks - when you create them you have to pass in an extra parameter to the [`CreateSymbolicLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866.aspx) API.

There is a subtle hint as to this behavior in the API documentation, where it states:

> To remove a symbolic link, delete the file (using [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915.aspx) or similar APIs) or remove the directory (using [`RemoveDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365488.aspx) or similar APIs) depending on what type of symbolic link is used.

This strongly indicates that APIs that work on files will not work on directory symlinks.

Now as to how to copy it, I strongly expect you'll have to create the symbolic link again, the process for this is to read the symlink target and then create the link a second time in the destination; something akin to (no error handling at all, transforms relative links to absolute links):

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile(srcFile, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
TCHAR outbuffer[2048];
DWORD written = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, outbuffer, 2048, 0);
CreateSymbolicLink(targetFile, outbuffer, SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY);
CloseHandle(h);
```

Now to create the symlink using the underlying reparse point data things get a little more complicated. If you don't have `ntifs.h` then you need to define the Microsoft reparse point data structure (copied from [the MSDN page for REPARSE_DATA_STRUCTURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552012.aspx)):

```
typedef struct _REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER {
  ULONG  ReparseTag;
  USHORT ReparseDataLength;
  USHORT Reserved;
  union {
    struct {
      USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
      USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
      USHORT PrintNameOffset;
      USHORT PrintNameLength;
      ULONG  Flags;
      WCHAR  PathBuffer[1];
    } SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer;
    struct {
      USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
      USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
      USHORT PrintNameOffset;
      USHORT PrintNameLength;
      WCHAR  PathBuffer[1];
    } MountPointReparseBuffer;
    struct {
      UCHAR DataBuffer[1];
    } GenericReparseBuffer;
  };
} REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER, *PREPARSE_DATA_BUFFER;
```

We change the routine:

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile(srcFile, 0,
  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0,
  OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, 0);
if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  char tmpBuffer[32 * 1024];
  REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER *repBuffer = reinterpret_cast<REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER *>(tmpBuffer);
  DWORD retBytes;
  if (DeviceIoControl(h, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, 0, 0, (void *)tmpBuffer,
      sizeof tmpBuffer, &retBytes, 0)) {
    if (repBuffer->ReparseTag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK) {
      wchar_t dest[2048];
      memcpy(dest, repBuffer->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer +
                   repBuffer->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameOffset / sizeof(wchar_t),
                   repBuffer->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength);
      dest[repBuffer->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength / sizeof(wchar_t)] = 0;
      if (!CreateSymbolicLink(targetFile, dest, SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY)) {
        // Error Handling
      }
    }
  }
  CloseHandle(h);
} else {
  // Open Error Handling
}
```

It's significantly more complicated, but it preserves the symbolic link in it's underlying form, i.e. if it's a relative link, then the created link will also be a relative link. In addition if the target does not exist the link still gets created.

This still does not remove the need to be either (a) an administrator, or (b) edited the group policy to [permit non-admin users to create symbolic links](https://superuser.com/questions/104845/permission-to-make-symbolic-links-in-windows-7).

Comment: OK. Thanks. I see why I'm getting an error. Still, my question remains. How to copy that link?

Comment: You will probably have to recreate it.

Comment: Why don't you add a `CloseHandle` call to your pseudo-code sample and I'll mark it as the answer. It seems to do the job. The downside of this approach though is that one needs to run as an administrator for it to work. That is needed to obtain the `SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_NAME` privilege that is needed for `CreateSymbolicLink` to succeed.

Comment: The only suspicion I have is that the way this works is to resolve the link and create a new one at the destination point; which means that if the link was not resolvable at the time this was created it would not work. I'm going to see about getting the underlying reparse point data and using that instead.

Comment: I've added code to use the underling reparse point data when creating the link which will preserve links in the case that the link target does not currently exist. You can edit the group policy to permit ordinary users to create symbolic links.

Comment: Good. Thanks. You may also want to account for `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT`. I'm not exactly sure but that may be a `folder junction`. The rest of your code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found this old thread as I was searching for answers on CopyFileEx behavior with the COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK flag set. I have code that does this, and all it does is create empty files with the right name. They are not functional symbolic links. I even ran with elevated privileges (the code runs as Administrator, with the SE_BACKUP_NAME, SE_RESTORE_NAME privileges -- even tried adding SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_NAME explicitly), but no change.

I also ran Robocopy with the /SL switch -- it too merely creates these useless, empty files. Seems like a CopyFileEx bug (Windows 10 x64).

PeteSh's code should work (I haven't tried it), but it is a shame that CopyFileEx does not work as advertised.